# Is it possible to decomplie any exe to .net source code (Visual studio)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exe

I have an exe file which is written in .net language . I have no source code for same but I want to change some functionality in this so convert it to visual studio source code. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

have a look on IL Spy-
https://www.gallery.expression.microsoft.com/8ef1d688-f80c-4380-8004-2ec7f814e7de

Also you can download it from here-
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/ILSpy/2.0/ILSpy_Master_2.1.0.1603_RTW_Binaries.zip/download.
Just unzip the contents in a folder somewhere - no installer.  Then run ILSpy.exe.

Comment: Thanks .I have tried it but How can I extract exe using this